# Kendo UI MVC not renderingsimple controls

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using kendo MVC UI. I have placed a button to test. I have setup every thing. Solution is being build but button is being rendered as a simple button it don't have k- classes and image that I mentioned.

```html
@(Html.Kendo().Button() .Name("btn") .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button}) .ImageUrl(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/qbo.png")) .Content("This Button"))
```

The above html is rendered as:

```html
<button class="element-center" id="btn" type="button">This Button</button>
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. MVC wrapper script was placed before kendo script files. I have deferred the script rendering, now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're missing an " after the type attribute

> type = "button

Anyways take a look to the [examples](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/button/images)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
    .Name("imageButton")
    .HtmlAttributes( new {type = "button"} )
    .ImageUrl(Url.Content("~/Content/shared/icons/sports/snowboarding.png"))
    .Content("Image icon"))
```